# How can I tell who calls System.gc()?

Tags: java, logging, garbage-collection, stack-trace

In a running system, we see lots of "Full GC (System)" which indicates someone triggers System.gc().

Is there a way to find out where in the code this happens?

I did search all the available source but found nothing suspicious so it must be somewhere, probably another app that's running in the same container or the container itself.

Comment: Simple solution: start your application in debug mode and put a method breakpoint at `System.gc()` (and `Runtime.gc()` for good measure).

Comment: @Aaron, You have over 50 questions without an accepted answer. Perhaps you could follow up answers so they are acceptable.

Comment: I see what you mean. Some of my questions are probably too complex for SO; the existing answers are not satisfactory (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136769/secure-web-login-example-tutorial or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135570/cyclic-buffer-with-readers).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the Runtime class to log where gc() is being called to a file (System.gc() calls Runtime.gc())

To do this, edit a copy, compile it and add it to your `-Xbootclasspath/p:`

However a high number of Full GC is more likely to be due to insufficient survivor space or a full tenured space.

Can you try running

```
jstat -gccause {pid} 5s
```

Comment: You can't really change the Runtime class though, as far as I can see, because gc() is a native method.  You can change System.gc(), but this is not the only place that can call Runtime.getRuntime().gc() - one example is sun.management.MemoryImpl.  Of course a library could call it this way too so the log in System might not tell you everything.

Answer (score 3):

Some library which you use might call explicit gc. You can disable it with `-XX:-DisableExplicitGC` and take a look if it stops `Full GC` in the logs

Comment: Good point; that way, I can quickly distinguish between explicit GC calls and "out of memory" invocations.

Answer (score 3):

Use following brace script & **jvisualvm** with **btrace plugin** will reveal the caller of `System.gc` easily.

```
// import all BTrace annotations
import com.sun.btrace.annotations.*;

// import statics from BTraceUtils class
import static com.sun.btrace.BTraceUtils.*;

// @BTrace annotation tells that this is a BTrace program
@BTrace
public class GCcaller {
    // @OnMethod annotation tells where to probe.
    // In this example, we are interested in entry
    // into the Thread.start() method.
    @OnMethod(
        clazz="java.lang.System",
        method="gc"
    )
    public static void func() {
        // println is defined in BTraceUtils
        // you can only call the static methods of BTraceUtils
        println("about to start a System.gc!");
        jstack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java you cannot "call" the garbage collector. If you see the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29) when you call to the method System.gc(), the vm just takes as a suggestion to run the garbage collector, but there is no guarantee that is effectively called. Is an internal process that will be called automatically even if you don't call when it needs space in the stack.

If you are seeing a lot of Full GC, it may be a symptom of the application not releasing the resources correctly. You should monitor the heap to see what's the problem

Comment: +1 Good point. In my case, a tool was used to analyze the problem and it said "17 out of 449 collections (3,786%) were triggered by System.gc() calls."